# Jquery ordering table rows

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following code to order table rows and it works pretty much as I need.

```
var $table=$('#Frm1');
var rows = $table.find('tr.grp').get();
rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    var keyA = $(a).attr('data-site');
    var keyB = $(b).attr('data-site');
    if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
    if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
    return 0;
});
$.each(rows, function(index, row) {
    $table.children('tbody').append(row);
})
```

However some of the entries don't have a value associated with `data-site`. The attribute is there, but not set.

These rows get added to the top of the table, I'd like them to be at the bottom of the table **before** table row with id `ID=LastGroup`

Can anyone advise how I can do this ?

Thanks

Comment: I tried to allow for them using: 
`if (!keyA || keyA > keyB) return 1;
if (!keyB || keyA < keyB) return -1;`  but that placed them at the top of the table still

Comment: That was my first thought too, but it doesn't work correctly. Doing them beforehand does, though.

Comment: Adding this to just above the if statements seems to work.. `     if (keyA === '' || keyB === '') return -9999;`  where 9999 is larger than the number of rows in the table !  no idea why !

Comment: @Tom, the `sort` function expect `-1`, `0`, `1`, not `-9999`

Comment: Thats what I assumed, I tried it randomly and it worked.. but I don't know why ..

Comment: You have an answer by @T.J.Crowder here... did you check it?

Comment: @Dekel - I'd miss read his reply.  adding `if (!keyA || !keyB) return -1;` above the if statements does appear to work

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - if you'v like to add this as an answer I'll accept it :) Thanks

Comment: I added an answer that also gives a solution for the `LastGroup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the attribute is there but has no value, the value you'll get from `attr` will be `""`. So just allow for that:

```
if (!keyA) return 1;
if (!keyB) return -1;
if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
```

Example:

```js
$("#sort").on("click", function() {
  var $table = $('#Frm1');
  var rows = $table.find('tr.grp').get();
  rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    var keyA = $(a).attr('data-site');
    var keyB = $(b).attr('data-site');
    if (!keyA) return 1;
    if (!keyB) return -1;
    if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
    if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
    return 0;
  });
  $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
    $table.children('tbody').append(row);
  });
});
```

```html
<table id="Frm1">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="grp" data-site="c"><td>c</td></tr>
    <tr class="grp" data-site="a"><td>a</td></tr>
    <tr class="grp" data-site="b"><td>b</td></tr>
    <tr class="grp" data-site><td>(none)</td></tr>
    <tr class="grp" data-site="q"><td>q</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" id="sort" value="Sort">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks that sorted it

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on @T.J.Crowder's answer.
If you want to check speifically for the `tr` with `id="LastGroup"` you should check it before any other checks you do:

```
if ($(a).attr('id') == 'LastGroup') {
    return 1;
}
if ($(b).attr('id') == 'LastGroup') {
    return -1;
}
```

```js
$("#sort").on("click", function() {
  var $table = $('#Frm1');
  var rows = $table.find('tr.grp').get();
  rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    var keyA = $(a).attr('data-site');
    var keyB = $(b).attr('data-site');
    if ($(a).attr('id') == 'LastGroup') {
      return 1;
    }
    if ($(b).attr('id') == 'LastGroup') {
      return -1;
    }
    if (!keyA) return 1;
    if (!keyB) return -1;
    if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
    if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
    return 0;
  });
  $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
    $table.children('tbody').append(row);
  });
});
```

```html
<table id="Frm1">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="grp" data-site="a" id="LastGroup"><td>this should be last</td></tr>
    <tr class="grp" data-site="c"><td>c</td></tr>
    <tr class="grp" data-site="a"><td>a</td></tr>
    <tr class="grp" data-site="b"><td>b</td></tr>
    <tr class="grp" data-site><td>(none)</td></tr>
    <tr class="grp" data-site="q"><td>q</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" id="sort" value="Sort">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```